# Grails multi-select does not save options when going from 3 to 2 options

Tags: grails, has-many, multi-select

I have a domain object category with an hasMany relation to domain object attributes

```
class Category {
    static hasMany = [attributes: Attribute]
    ...
}
```

I used scaffolding to generate a multi select box.

```
<g:select name="attributes" from="${Attribute.list()}" multiple="multiple" optionKey="id" size="5" value="${categoryInstance?.attributes*.id}" class="many-to-many"/>
```

I can use this to select box to select 1, 2, 3, etc. options.

But when there are 3 options selected and I select 2 options, it will not save the options. It  will still have the 3 options that were selected before. The same happens when going from 4 options to 3 etc.

When I go back to selecting 1 option. Everything works again.

Does anyone else has the same problem?

Is this a know bug? (I could not find it)

Is there a workaround?

Comment: have you checked, that actually gets submitted (e.g. with some web developer tools like firebug) and do you check your `category.save()` call for errors?

Comment: Yes, I did. The new ids are submitted. The update does not contain errors. It just has the old attributes in the set. The new ids are in the params. So I did find a workaround, but I don't like it.       categoryInstance.attributes.clear()
        params.attributes.each { it ->
            categoryInstance.attributes.add(Attribute.findById(it as Long))
        }

Answer (score 0):

The workaround posted by @Renso didn't work for me when only 1 option is selected, it ends up iterating over each character of the 1 attribute as `it` rather than as a single String of the id. Here's what I did to take that into account.

```
categoryInstance.attributes.clear()
if(params.attributes instanceof String) params.attributes = [params.attributes]
params.attributes.each { it -> categoryInstance.attributes.add(Attribute.findById(it as Long)) }
```